# Error when i try to pass an array using putExtra and get it in another activity

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to pass a String Array from one activity to another, which is a ListActivity. I need this array to populate the ListActivity.
This is the code, but it doesn't work, it crashes: 
First class, from where i want to send:

```
package com.example.browser3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Settings2 extends Activity{

EditText etAdress;
Button bAdd;
Button bRemove;
Button bMenu;
String[] array={};
int counter=0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.settings2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    bMenu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bMenu);

    bMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickHome();                
        }
    });

    etAdress=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdress);

    bAdd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            array[counter]=etAdress.getText().toString();
            counter++;
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putStringArray("key", array);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings2.this, Favorite.class);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);


        }           

    });
private void clickHome(){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.browser3.MENU"));
}
}
```

And this is the Code for the second class, which should receive:

```
package com.example.browser3;



import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Favorite extends ListActivity {

String[] elements={};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
HomePage object=new HomePage();

public void setElements(int position,String element) {
    elements[position]=element;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  elements = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("name");
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorite.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , elements));
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    elements=intent.getExtras().getStringArray("key");
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.browser3.HomePage");// ce e aici aia porneste la click
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Favorite.this , ourClass);
    String s=elements[position];
    writeFile("history.txt",s);
    ourIntent.putExtra("name", s);
    startActivity(ourIntent);


            }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void writeFile(String fileName, String x) {

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                fileName, MODE_APPEND));
        out.write(x + "\n");

        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

None of the questions I've looked at so far have solved my problem.

It crashes when I start the Favorite activity. This is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.browser3/com.example.browser3.Favorite}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.example.browser3.Favorite.onCreate(Favorite.java:31)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the exception that it crashes with. Is it a null pointer or something else?

Comment: i don't know how to get that answer for you...

Comment: if you are very kind, i can give you the project, i am desperate

Comment: When it crashes look in log cat and you should see a bunch of red text. Just copy and paste that here. Also just looking over your code it looks like your not initializing your array until after your using it. That could maybe cause a null pointer.

Comment: Something on line 31 of Favorite.java is `null`. Which line is that?

Comment: i sent you man. thanks

Comment: elements=intent.getExtras().getStringArray("key");

Comment: Sid, i sent you the project. did you receive it? my mail is petradu2@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing you code, I got the reason for Null pointer

You are trying to get the bundle value on load of Favorites which is wrong because you are assigning the bundle value only in setting2 page if user tries to load it from Home page it is looking for bundle value, as you have not assigned anything over there it is crashing with null pointer. So try to pass one more string with the value activity so that you can check on Favorites page where the call is
 coming from, if it is from Home do nothing if it is from Settings2 do as per the bundle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will crash because you are using elements before you instatiate the var elements.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorite.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , elements));
Intent intent = getIntent();
elements=intent.getExtras().getStringArray("key");
```

And this won't work if you remove the // because "name" is no key in your StringArrayExtras

```
// elements = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 31 of Favourite activity is throwing null pointer exception.
You dont have to use bundle to pass value. You can simply use intent in Setting2 activity like this:

```
intent.putExtra("key", array); 
startActivity(intent);
```

And from your Favourite activity, you can get array by following code:

```
elements = new String[];
elements= getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("key");
```